# Shippitjs running tasks before deploy

Tags: javascript, deployment

With [shipitjs](https://github.com/shipitjs/shipit) I'm trying to "build all the things" locally before shippitjs syncs them up to the server. However I can't work out how to have it wait until my bower and composer tasks have completed before it deploys.

```
require('shipit-deploy')(shipit);
require('shipit-shared')(shipit);

/* config ... */

shipit.task('composer:install', function() {
    return shipit.local('composer --install --optimize --prefer-dist ', {cwd:shipit.config.workspace});
});

shipit.task('bower:install', function() {
    return shipit.local('bower install', {cwd:shipit.config.workspace});
});

shipit.on('fetched',function(){
    shipit.start('composer:install','bower:install');
});
```

I end up having the code deployed before bower is done.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but it can still be useful. You could try the following :

```
require('shipit-deploy')(shipit);
require('shipit-shared')(shipit);

/* config ... */

shipit.task('composer:install', function() {
    return shipit.local('composer --install --optimize --prefer-dist ', {cwd:shipit.config.workspace});
    return shipit.emit('bower_install');
});

shipit.task('bower:install', function() {
    shipit.local('bower install', {cwd:shipit.config.workspace});
    return shipit.emit('deploy');
});

shipit.on('bower_install', function() {
    return shipit.start('bower:install');
})

shipit.on('predeploy',function(){
    shipit.start('composer:install');
})

shipit.on('deploy',function(){
    shipit.start('deploy:init');
})
```

This solution waits for the task bower:install and composer:install to finish before launching the deployment.

Comment: How does the event `predeploy` get fired here?

Answer (score 0):

Old question yes, but new Stack in where you'll find a lot of examples for your request.

I made a WordPress development stack using Shipit JS instead of Capistrano because I'm not comfortable with Ruby. Maybe that can help. Feel to use it and/or post some issues if needed. Regards.

[WP-Jungle / Bonzai](https://github.com/wp-jungle/bonzai)

[Bonzai's Shipit tasks](https://github.com/wp-jungle/bonzai-core/blob/master/src/grunt/tasks/publish.js#L73): you'll see here that I'm using `this.async()` as the second argument which should solve your issue.